# How to move to next textField when QuickType suggestion is chosen?

Tags: ios, swift

I have three text fields on my screen; the first two are first and last names. I have enabled QuickType so the names can be chosen quickly. When the first name is selected by the QuickType button, I wish the last name text field to become the first responder, and similarly for the third textField to become the first responder when the last name is tapped in the QuickType bar.

Currently, the user has to tap the QuickType bar and then press Return or tap in the next field.

I wonder if there is a way to register when the QuickType bar is pressed as opposed to the main body of the keyboard, or alternatively if there is a way to register when more than one character is entered at the same time? Or if there is some other way of enabling this behavior?

I have seen it in action in other apps, but can't find a solution despite looking.

Thoughts would be very helpful, please!

Comment: Does `textFieldShouldReturn` get called when using the QuickType bar?

Comment: Unfortunately not (at least not without adding to the standard code in a way I'm not aware of)

Comment: I'm asking the obvious, but did you set the textField delegate?

Comment: Thanks Don; yes if I hit the "Return" button I can move to the next textField as expected; I want to move without the user having to hit "Return" as well as filling the field with the QuickType suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If string.count > 1, then the user isn't manually typing. This is just an example, you'll need to check the textField to see if it's for first name, last name, etc. and act accordingly.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
  if string.count > 1 {
    textField.text = string
    nextTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
  }
  return true
}
```

Comment: I needed to use return false if string.count > 1 and return true if not so that the string didn't get copied to the next textfield (for future people reading this). Very happy and thanks for the solution.